# Mixing EQ, the Mix

Tags: mixing, eq, techniques

When you are mixing and you are using EQ, how are you supposed to do it?

Are you supposed to put an EQ on a track and arm all the automations for it and then use the automations each time you want to EQ a region on the track?

Is there an easy way to write plug-in automation to a track without a controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way for me is to make a selection on the region i want to eq, then use Preview mode, do the eq i want and capture, then write to all

Alternatively, to make a selection on the region i want to eq and loop play it with the automation in write mode and tweak until it sounds like i want it to. just dont forget to put the track back to read mode if you don't have the switch to latch after automation pass activated on the preferences.

Comment: What is write to all, I have never heard of that??

Comment: Oh never-mind, it's only available with the CPTK and HD.  

Answer (score 5):

I put an EQ on all dialogue tracks.

First I apply a general lo-cut and a general hi-cut to all tracks. The hi-cut will be somewhere around 13k and the lo-cut somewhere between 80-125 Hz, depending on how it all sounds. I always use steep 24 dB filters.

Normally I work on HD, so I also use the automation preview to find the right EQ, and then write to all. I am almost always in touch mode.

If I am working on LE, I tweak the controls with the mouse, but I will probably be in latch mode, so it doesn't snap back all the time...

You can also press cmd+ctrl while clicking on a control, and then the parameter graph pops up on the track, so you can make quick general changes.

Comment: nice shortcut tip with the cmd+ctrl click @Morten

Answer (score 0):

Option+apple+question mark (?) is the capture hot key when in preview mode